# Question about the proof for the derivative of the inverse function

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

I am trying to prove that the inverse function of a differentiable function is also differentiable.

Here is what I did: There exists $x$ and $x_0$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $f(x_0)=y_0$. Thus:
$$\lim_{y \to \ y_0} \frac{f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y_0)}{y - y_0} = \lim_{y \to \ y_0} \frac{f^{-1}(f(x)) - f^{-1}(f(x_0)}{f(x) - f(x_0)}\\
=\lim_{y \to \ y_0} \frac{x - x_0}{f(x) - f(x_0)}=\lim_{y \to \ y_0} \frac{1}{\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}}.$$

I know that it's equal to $\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$ but I don't know how to explain why the fact that $y$ approaches $y_0$ implies that $x$ approaches $x_0$ so I will be able to use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: You'll run into problems at points where the derivative is zero.

Comment: @DavidMitra I know, I am proving this for when the derivative isn't zero.

Comment: As all differentiable functions, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and its inverse function is continuous at $y_0=f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x=f^{-1}(y)$, so when $y \to y_0,\, x \to f^{-1}(y_0)$.

Also, we have $x_0=f^{-1}(y_0)$ , so $x \to x_0$.

Comment: You should mention that $f$ as well as $f^{-1}$ are continuous. This is not automatic but is a consequence of the fact that $f'(x_0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Daniel knows that. Read his comment.

Comment: The askers question is about why $x\to x_0$. This is because of continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $x_0$ and the continuity follows by the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ and derivative $f'(x_0)\neq 0$. I don't think asker is aware of this otherwise the question wouldn't arise.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh He is. He says in his comment that he’s looking to prove this where $f’(x) \ne 0$. The OP wants to solely know why $y\to y_0 \implies x\to x_0$, according to the post.

Comment: Yes and that implication is a consequence of continuity as described in my comment. Your answer doesn't say anything about continuity.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Specifying that explicitly isn’t needed because we’re dealing with the case where it’s always continuous.

Comment: You had better take a look at my answer where I provide all the hypotheses. Any theorem or formula must contain the hypotheses under which it is valid. Like one says that Pythagoras theorem is valid if and only if the triangle is right angled.

Comment: @I understand that continuity is needed, but what I’m saying and will say again is that continuity is already **provided** because $f^{-1}(x)$ never equals $0$ in the asker’s problem. Furthermore, this is not a formal answer, but one which is specifically suited to the needs of the asker. It’s not for you.

Comment: Let the asker decide what is suitable for him or her. The tradition of avoiding rigor in calculus has already caused a lot of damage. The students need not be shown all proofs but they must know their theorems precisely. If things were that obvious as you think the asker wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh  I don’t think the rigor you’re putting into this was at all the motive of this question. I’m pretty sure the asker knows about the continuity and the question he posed is clear in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version of the rule for derivative of inverse functions.

> **Theorem**: Let $f$ be a real valued function defined in a certain neighborhood $I$ of $x_0$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$. Also let $f$ be strictly monotone and continuous on $I$ with $f'(x_0)\neq 0$. Then there is a neighborhood $J$ of $y_0$ such that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is defined, strictly monotone and continuous on $J$ and further derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $y_0$ equals $1/f'(x_0)$.

The hypotheses of continuity and monotone nature of $f$ are needed to get a well behaved inverse. And the result above tells that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $J$ and in particular at $y_0$ hence as $y=f(x) $ tends to $y_0$ the variable $x=f^{-1}(y)$ tends to $f^{-1}(y_0)=x_0$ and your proof can be completed.

Most introductory calculus books do not state precisely the conditions under which a theorem is valid. So you may miss such detail regarding continuity while dealing with derivatives of inverse functions.